# P-time reduction A < B where B has no no-instance

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

I had a question to prove whether a reduction can exist $A < B$, if B has no no instances and one yes instance. I am not sure if this is too trivial.

Let $A \in P$ and $Y$ be the only yes-instance for $B$.
I build a TM, $M$ that solves $A$ in $P$-time. I build $T_y1$ and $T_y2$ which erase the input and writes the code of Y. I mark the first as an accept state and the latter as a reject. I build a machine M that gets the output of $T$, if $T$ accepts, it goes to $T_y$, if it rejects it goes to $T_y1$, otherwise $T_y2$.

Is this approach correct or too simplistic? or even, can such reduction happen?

Comment: No, you completely changed the question from $B$ having no "no" instances (which is what the title still says, by the way) to $B$ having exactly one "yes" instance.

Comment: it still had no no instances but one yes. And in the rest of the question it said 'Y the only yes-instance'. I don't think I completely changed the question, unless I am missing something that I am not understanding

Comment: Any decision problem has an infinite number of instances. Every instance is either a "yes" instance or a "no" instance. So, if there is exactly one "yes" instance, there must be infinitely many "no" instances.

Comment: Uhm. So you are saying that such B can't exist? hence there is no reduction?

Comment: Correct: $B$ can't exist with the properties you describe.  (Because they contradict each other, I didn't notice you were requiring both no "noes" and exactly one "yes", which is why I thought you'd changed the question more than you had.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's not strictly correct; there are finite decision problems, even if they are trivial in the complexity theoretic sense.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean "at least one yes instance"?

Comment: @Raphael They're only finite as promise problems, aren't they? Given a question such as "Is the input a 3-colourable graph on ten or fewer vertices?", the input could be a no instance either by having more than ten vertices (there are infinitely many of these) or by being non-3-colourable. (Potentially, even by not being a graph at all.)